# Why is the reason for the down and close vote for this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closing, down-votes

> **[Closed and reopened](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2844469/revisions)**

I'm member of this site for almost 3 years, and I cannot understand why [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2844469/proving-that-fx-y-frac1x2-y2-is-not-integrable-both-on-b2-ve) question takes one down vote and 4 close votes. Can someone who can understand the reason for this explain it to me, please. Which rule that I'm not following, or which criteria does that question fail to fill?

Comment: corresponding review results [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/1036962)

Comment: Thanks for informing @JohnMa. I did not know that we have such an interface for the close&open votes.

Answer (score 7):

I'm guessing because it is long and the poster has been argumentative with people pointing out things in the mathematics that haven't made sense, with interpretations of the wording in the question that are unjustified, etc. This leads to

1. It being unclear exactly what is being asked: are they asking about the validity of their math, or about the correctness of their interpretation of the wording in the question?
2. It comes across as not being thought through very well. If requests for clarification are blown off as "not being important" or result in drastic changes in the post, it feels capricious and some people will simply downvote to discourage the frustration level associated with the post. (**edit:** or vote to close. It has really only received one downvote, I don't know that I would read anything into that.)

Comment: The question is long ? Morgan, I can assure you that this is quite a normal question in size; I would expect you to know that, as you also a member of this site for 3 years.

Comment: Moreover, I have explicitly put a section with the title "**Question**", how can the question be unclear ?

Comment: Addition to that, if the argument that the people make do not make sense, is this the fault of the question or the OP ?

Comment: Morgan suggests that "the poster has been argumentative," and the poster immediately replies by ... being argumentative. Case closed.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I actually couldn't understand what you mean.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I mean if you mean that the problem was the poster, it has been replaced thanks to XanderHenderson

Comment: When Morgan wrote, "I'm guessing because it is long and the poster has been argumentative with people," who or what do you suppose Morgan meant by "the poster," onurcanbektas?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ok, I got that, but as I have said in my second comment, poster has been removed.

Comment: Plus, it that was the issue, why the reason for the "hold on" says that "question is unclear" ?

Comment: Sorry, onurcanbektas, I don't think you do get it. What was removed was an image. Morgan didn't say the image was argumentative with people – I don't think it makes any sense to call an image argumentative – Morgan wrote that the poster was argumentative with people. The poster. The person who posted.

Comment: @onurcanbektas I did mean "poster" as in "the person who posted the question", I was not referring to the graphic.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Ok, now I get it.

Answer (score -5):

I hope others will correct me if they think I'm mistaken, but there are two issues:

- The scanned image is a bit of a no-no to some users as these links a) aren't searchable and b) often subsequently break, leaving an unintelligible question.
- But the main thing I think, is that there are two camps of users:

  - Most users (me included) see this as a question and answer site in which people ask and answer questions.  Reasonable questions and answers are acceptable, and those which have particularly resonant, lasting importance, will gain particularly high prominence by virtue of receiving a high number of upvotes.  Less-useful questions and answers receive less prominence due to not receiving the same number of upvotes - but are still there for those who may want to dig for them.
  - The 2nd camp of users choose not to rely upon the upvote/downvote system to curate the content on the site.  They proactively curate the content and their vision is more akin to a canonical repository of a single copy of each maths question.  Variants, special cases and inquiries into rarely considered details which they only foresee being of relevance to the original poster, are to be removed as they're not up to the high editorial standards they wish to maintain.  Some of the users in this camp are among the most generous contributors to the site.

I think most likely that there were some users in the 2nd camp who felt your question did not meet their curation standards.

Comment: This is more like a complaint to the existing situation than to answer this particular question.

Comment: @JohnMa in my opinion a statement like that carries more weight when accompanied by a better hypothesis for an answer to the question asked.